# grails: findallbyidinlist method

Tags: grails, methods, controller

In my grails project, I've used the method `Object.findAllByIdInList()`, passing a list as parameter.
The code used is the following:

`def allSelectedIds = ReceiptItem.findAllByIdInList(par)`

In which the ReceiptItem is a domain class defined as follows:

```
class Receipt {
    double totalAmount;
    Date releaseDate;
    int vatPercentage;
    int discount;
    Boolean isPayed;
    Boolean isInvoice;
    static belongsTo = [patient:Patient]
    static hasMany = [receiptItems:ReceiptItem]

    static constraints = {
        receiptItems(blank:  false)
        patient(blank: false)
        totalAmount(blank: false)
        vatPercentage(blank: false, nullable: false)
    }
}
```

and `par` is the list of ids defined as follows:

```
def par = params.list("receiptItemsSelected")
```

`receiptItemsSelected` is defined in the gsp page into the `remoteFunction()` as follows:

```
params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + jQuery(this).val()'
```

The problem is that the line above throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long. Stacktrace follows:
Message: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I don't understand why it is throwing this exception.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Probably list `par` has `ids` as `String`. Generally `id` for domain objects is stored as `Long`. Try this instead

`ReceiptItem.findAllByIdInList(par*.toLong())`

*Also make sure that `id` represented as string `isNumber()`.

```
assert !'C'.isNumber()
assert '4'.isNumber()
```

Comment: the toLong() method does not exists for me

Comment: @FrancescoDS It does for Groovy. Whenever in doubt search for it or test it yourself in Groovy/Grails Console. Here, test this: `assert [1L, 2L, 3L] == ['1', '2', '3']*.toLong()`. (Do not fully rely on the IDE you are working on.)

Comment: You are right...it works...but it does not work if par contains more than 1 element...The exception thrown is the following: NumberFormatException. It seems that par* does not take all elements. Any suggestion?

Comment: The "strange" thing is that if I perform par.size() it always returns 1...but if I print par elements, I see, for example [1,2]. Maybe is there some problem with def par = params.list("receiptItemsSelected") ?